# Adding entry for linux using EasyBCD

Tags: linux, easybcd

I've installed Linux as dual boot with windows10 pre-installed (in Legacy mode) and I want to add a new entry to the Windows(10) boot loader using EasyBCD but the Linux partitions are not shown in the EasyBCD!! Do you have a solution to this problem?

[image]